# Regular expression not matching word pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have written code in Java which will return `true` if the matching string contains word or words. But it is returning `false`.

```
public class RegexTestStrings {
  public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "This is my small example "
      + "string which I'm going to " + "use for pattern matching.";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(EXAMPLE_TEST.matches("(\\w)*"));
  }
}
```

Can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: why are you using groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`matches()` tests the entire string. You need to use `find()` or extend your regex with `.*`:

```
.*(\\w)+.*
```

Please note, that I changed `*` to `+`.

I would prefer `find()` for performance reasons.

Comment: this matchs ".." too and any non empty string. Maybe ".*(\\w)+.*" is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to test if the string match and you don't need to get the group, this should suffice

```
".*\\w+.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) \w matches letters and numbers, not white spaces or symbols.

Answer (score 0):

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

> \w          A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]

As you see there is no space, no single quote and no dot. So your regexp cannot match the test string since it contains those charachtes.

The following prints true for your test string

```
System.out.println(EXAMPLE_TEST.matches("(\\w|\\s|\\p{Punct})*"));
```